# Can't get Java Resource file in AWS Lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-lambda, pg-jdbc

I am trying to configure an SSL connection between PostgreSQL and AWS Lambda. The problem is passing the AWS certificate PEM file to pgjdbc.

I added the PEM file to my resources folder and tried to get it's location with:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem").toString();
```

And it returns:

`file:/var/task/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem`

But if I pass that as the `sslrootcert` property, I get an exception:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Could not open SSL root certificate file file:/var/task/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem.

I then decided to run a code that prints all directories and files names from my Lambda, staring with the current folder, and I get the `rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem` file at the current directory.

What's the correct way to get a PEM file from my resources and pass it to pgjdbc then?

Answer (score 2):

So this won't fix the problem described here, but it will solve my issue at configuring pgjdbc.

If you want to pass a Certificate PEM file to pgjdbc, as a resource file, add the following configuration to your properties file:

```
sslfactory = org.postgresql.ssl.SingleCertValidatingFactory
sslfactoryarg = classpath:rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem
```

`SingleCertValidatingFactory` accepts other kinds of references to the file, as a classhpath, a file path, an environment variable, a system variable or the Certificate text itself. For more information, see the class docs [here](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/ssl/SingleCertValidatingFactory.java).

Comment: Thank you very much. We were struggling with exactly the same problem regarding the SSL root certificate, postgres and RDS.

Comment: My pleasure, don't forget to upvote it, so others will be able to see this as a valuable post.